# Httputility.urldecode replacement in .Net4?

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, system.web

I got an *`old Program(class library)`* developed by *`.Net 2`*. Recently I want to use that Program in new project which is use *`.Net4(For new WPF feature's )`*. so there is a big problem:

> .Net4 don't support **System.Web** and as result it can't be use **Httputility.urldecode**!!

So what is **`urldecode`** jop? and how can I change that to something, which is support by *`.Net4`*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to run against the client profile (which doesnt include HttpUtility) then you could check this [Alternative to HttpUtility for .NET 3.5 SP1 client framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315/alternative-to-httputility-for-net-3-5-sp1-client-framework). (That question is about 3.5 sp1 but nothing has changed in this regard in 4.0)

You really should see if you can't just use the full framework though.

Answer (score 10):

HttpUtility is wild goose chase for c# users since it's not already there (referenced)
2 alternatives :

```
  string a =  System.Uri.EscapeUriString("https://some.url.goes.here"); // for path
  string b = System.Uri.EscapeDataString("parameter1=1&parameter2=something"); // for params
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, adding System.Web just for the sake of escaping and unescaping an string is just not the way to go.

Comment: Escape***String methods are a replacement for UrlEncode. For UrlDecode you need Uri,UnescapeDataString

Answer (score 3):

Try the UrlDecode method on HttpServerUtility:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in below link, .NET Framework 4 is supporting the HttpUtility.
As @Alun is mentioend above, I think you use .NET 4 Client Profile

[HttpUtility Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx)

Comment: oops you right .Net 4 client profile don't support that. but why?

Comment: Why is an excellent question. My guess would be that they just didn't think it through.