# httputility does not exist in current context in framework 3.5

Tags: c#, http, sharepoint, system.web

I'm trying to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` in my `sharepoint` project in the `framework 3.5` but it doesn't recognise it. Simply saying :

> HttpUtility does not exist in current context

I called `System.Web` but it still doesn't recognise none of the Http objects !

Comment: Did you reference System.Web.dll?

Comment: 1. Add reference to System.Web in project references. 2. Add `using System.Web;` to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to *System.Web.dll*

A *using System.Web* without the above reference will not suffice alone.

Unfortunately, the *System.Web.dll* cannot be referenced in a project that targets a Client Profile version of the .Net framework. So look at your project properties and make sure it targets ".NET Framework 3.5" and not ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile".

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here:
[Alternative to HttpUtility for .NET 3.5 SP1 client framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315/alternative-to-httputility-for-net-3-5-sp1-client-framework)

Another option if possible is to upgrade to .NET 4.5 then you have the option of using

```
WebUtility.UrlEncode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx