# HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method Not Resolved

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I used this Code in .net 3.5

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("", new UTF8Encoding()).Replace('+', ' ');
```

which worked fine, but I have compiled the project under .NET 4.0 and it is giving me this error:
`"The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context."`.

I added both `System.Web` and `System.Web.Extensions` references. This has not resolved[image] this error.

Comment: This looks similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020802/httputility-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-framework-3-5, make sure you are targeting the full Framework and not client profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change target framework form `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.Net Framework 4`

Comment: the problem persist i am using vs 2010

Comment: @Ammaedragas what does `Project/Properties/Application/TargetFramework` say?